# How do I make perfectly lined text to always fir the end of the line?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, less

I'm trying to create a column where the text perfectly fits the end of the line but I can't seem to get it working. I've also tried searching for it and found no solutions to this problem.

I need the text to end at the end of the column just like this webpage has :

https://www.realitnitrznice.cz/blog/4

I was trying to achieve this effect by setting max width :

```
.article-maxwidth{
  max-width: 40vw;
}
```

but it's extrememely inaccurate. I've also tried setting the w-75 for example which again showed to be very inaccurate. I've noticed that the webpage has it set with spaces somehow. If the text isn't long enough the page will fill in bigger spaces to somehow push the text to the end of the column.

Here's my current code that I'm trying to line :

```
<div class="wrapper container-fluid shorter">
        <div class="blog-body article-maxwidth">

            <h5 class="main-title">Jak postavit dům levně aneb proč jsou typové domy tak levné</h5>
            <p class="author"><i class="fas fa-pen-fancy"></i> Realitní tržnice</p>

            <p>Velmi často, když s někým řeším cenu stavby dochází na druhé straně k zděšení, jak je možné, že domy co navrhujeme jsou tak drahé. Ano všichni jsou často nadopovaní marketingovými steroidy, které na ně firmy prodávající typové projekty nebo typové domy chrlí.</p>

            <div class="image">
                <a href="images/5.jpg" data-rel="lightcase">
                    <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="Exotická kuchyně">
                </a>
                <span class="title">Exotická kuchyně</span>
            </div>

            <h2>Dlouhá cesta do ráje</h2>
            <p>Letiště v Bangkoku je krokem z komfortní zóny pro všechny, kdo se bojí sednout do letadla. Let do vysněného ráje trvá kolem 12 hodin s minimálně jedním přestupem v některé z evropských metropolí.    O přímé lince z Prahy do Bangkoku se    zatím pouze mluví, ale zdá se, že bychom se jí mohli v dohledné dočkat. Aby byla trasa pro letecké společnosti zajímavá z finančního hlediska, je nutné, aby ji využilo alespoň 30 000 cestujících    ročně, a to naše republika s přehledem    splňuje.</p>

            <div class="image">
                <a href="images/2.jpg" data-rel="lightcase">
                    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="Thajské pláže">
                </a>
                <span class="title">Thajské pláže</span>
            </div>

            <h2>Svobodně dýchejte</h2>
            <p>Kdysi se tahle země jmenovala Siam, což v překladu znamená „svoboda“. A svobodně se tu budete cítit i dnes. Své si tu najde milovník pulsujících velkoměst, který zaplesá nad svítícím a rušným    Bangkokem, ale i obdivovatelé panenské    přírody, národních parků s pralesy a vodopády nebo sněhobílých pláží. A až se unavíte sledováním okolních krás, pohodlně se usaďte a nechte si naservírovat cokoliv ze zdejší kuchyně. Vyhlášená je    po celém světě, ale můžeme vám    zaručit, že takové dobroty jako tady mimo území Thajska neochutnáte.</p>

            <!--<div class="image"><a href="blog/4/3.jpg" data-rel="lightcase"><img src="blog/4/6.jpg" alt="Taxi"></a></div>  <span class="title">Taxi</span> -->

            <h2>Kde složit hlavu</h2>
            <p>Zvlášť v hlavní sezóně, která trvá od listopadu do března, je radno domluvit si ubytování předem. Jestli toužíte po komfortu a hýčkání, zaměřte se na čtyřhvězdičkové rezorty. Za noc v nich    zaplatíte řádově méně než u nás a můžete se    spolehnout, že servis bude perfektní. Ubytování dokážete najít i na místě, ale obrňte se trpělivostí.</p>

            <div class="image">
                <a href="images/4.jpg" data-rel="lightcase">
                    <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="Noční ulice">
                </a>
                <span class="title">Noční ulice</span>
            </div>

            <h2>Vzpomínky na celý život</h2>
            <p>Ať zvolíte jakýkoliv typ svého pobytu v Thajsku, můžete se spolehnout, že vás ve všech ohledech nadchne. Výstražný prst bychom zvedli jen v jednom případě, a to jsou drogy. Jejich držení a    užívání je trestné a cizinci bývají snadným    terčem jak drogové mafie, tak policie.</p>

        </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone happen to know how can I achieve this? Any documentation that explains this issue in depth? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you looking for the [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) property?

Comment: Can you set     p{text-align: justify;}

Comment: Holy shit guys that was it! Thanks lol. It was so easy that no one thought someone would be so stupid to miss on that option in text-align. I legit used it milions of times and had no idea about this! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `text-align: justify` to make the text break at the place

```css
.article {
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil molestiae voluptatum sunt nostrum eos maxime in temporibus accusamus, a vero laudantium sapiente? Officiis minima animi magnam sequi recusandae reiciendis libero!</p>
</div>
```